# jqueryui's "Fold" effect is the only effect that works

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently I am experimenting with jqueryui hide() and show() functions. The only effect that i can get to work is the "fold" effect. I.e show("fold") and hide("fold") whenever i try another effect like "clip" or "fade", the effects do not work. Any reason why? Here is a snippet of the relevant code.

```
<script src="./jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
clickCB  = function()
{
$("#game-type").hide().show("fold").replaceWith("<p id=\"game-type\";>" + $(this).val() + " Testing Testing" + "</p>" );

};
</script>

<input class="someclass" type="radio" name="v" value="1" id="option1">
<label for="option1"> Game A </label><br>

<p id="game-type" style="display: none;">
</p>

<script>
$("input[name=v]").click(clickCB);
</script>
```

EDIT* I do not think it is a linking issue of any kind because i successfully got the accordion widget to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, back....

Can I suggest simplifying your entire line 7 to:

```
$("#game-type").html($(this).val() + " Testing Testing").show("highlight","slow");
```

.show() was operating on the original empty element, not the replacement. Why not simply use the original element?

The hide(), appears to be extraneous.  ...unless you are intending to toggle() that element's display?

Note: as we discussed, I did make (as you have made) use of a jQueryUI css file to display that 'highlight' effect.

Comment: Thanks again Matt! SO i figured out my problem. When i was replacing using replaceWith(), the animation was getting messed up because i was replacing the whole <p> element versus only replacing the contents within it.  I had no idea jquery had a .html() method which only replaces the contents. 

And yes, i was hiding first because i am toggling the elements display.Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Rockin!  Way to beat the bug into submission!

Answer (score 0):

One point - not a whole answer:  You're not using a jQueryUI style-sheet.  Some effects (highlight, for example) can't work as intended without it.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. I am actually using a style sheet in my original code, i just realized that i was using an older version. This did not solve my current issue, but has resolved other previous issues. Thanks!